# A button wont show up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.gelasoft.answeringball.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sphereIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/magicBallDescr"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sphereIcon"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/launch_codes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="106dp"
            android:hint="@string/textHint"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnAsk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/btnAskQ"           
         />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything is perfect, but the button won't show up.

What am I missing here? I know that is something basic even for a beginner, but I find it hard to understand as a newbie in the xml world.

Comment: Your inner `LinearLayout` has the orientation 'horizontal'. I guess your view can't show the TextView, EditText and Button in one row. There isn't that much space.

Comment: Particularly true, after the EditText takes all the remaining space after the TextView...

Comment: @Kody oh I see, now it showed up. Can you answer it, so I would be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner LinearLayout has the orientation 'horizontal'. I guess your view can't show the TextView, EditText and Button in one row. There isn't that much space.